# Not comparing dates

Tags: java, android, date

In my application, i want to compare two dates, my next_due date must be equal to and greater than current date. i code it but its not working:( What are the corrections in code so that i achieve the required result Kindly help

My JavaCode

```
public void CompareDates(){
      Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar next_due_on = Calendar.getInstance();

    if(date.before(next_due_on))
    System.out.print("Current date(" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").
    format(next_due_on.getTime()) + ") is greater than the given date " + new
    SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date.getTime()));
          else
      System.out.print("Both date are equal.");
      }

 date_txtbx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_txtbx);
        date_txtbx.setText(" " 
        + String.valueOf(java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                                    .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())));

        next_due_on_txtbx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.next_due_on_txtbx);
        next_due_on_txtbx.setText(non_ticket_task.next_due_on);
```

Comment: I am not getting the point in keepin both dates just Calendar's current instance! Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar next_due_on = Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: I use it for getting the calender date. is it not the correct way of getting it??

Comment: AFAIK, both variables date and next_due_on will be current date. Check that using debugging

Comment: @ShreyaShah same date, different time.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public boolean dateCompare(Date date1 , Date date2){

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(date1);
    Calendar next_due_on = Calendar.getInstance();
    next_due_on.setTime(date2);
    int temp = date.compareTo(next_due_on);
    if (temp == 0 || temp == -1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

temp will be 1,0,-1 you can make your choice and get boolean out of it

Comment: Simply `return (temp==0||temp==1)`

Comment: write your logic as per your need, temp will be 1,0,-1 you can make your choice and get boolean out of it

Comment: My friend, I mean that `if (temp == 0 || temp == 1)
        return true;
    return false;` is the same as `return (temp==0||temp==1);`. Also Java API [doesn't define it's 0, -1 and 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) but 0, <0  and >0. Watch out.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases when you do date manipulations you should use **joda-time**. You can find main page at:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

[image]

You can easily compare dates with methods `.isBefore()` and `isAfter()`

```
public boolean hasWordEnded(){

    String today = "24/12/2012";
    String endOfMayanCalendar = "21/12/2012";
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    DateTime todayDate = fmt.parseDateTime(today);
    DateTime endOfWorldDate = fmt.parseDateTime(endOfMayanCalendar);

    if (todayDate.isAfter(endOfWorldDate)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

May the force be with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar next_due_on = Calendar.getInstance();
```

come too fast, try

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar next_due_on = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(date.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(next_due_on.getTimeInMillis());
```

you will see that time in millis is the same

```
1356345814527
1356345814527
```

Comment: You don't `Calendar` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(isDueDateValid(dueDate));

    dueDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);    
    System.out.println(isDueDateValid(dueDate));

    dueDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2); 
    System.out.println(isDueDateValid(dueDate));
}



public static boolean isDueDateValid(Calendar dueDate)
{
    Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    return dueDate.after(currDate); 

}
```

Comment: just create your desired duedate object and pass the object as parameter in isDueDateValid method;

Answer (score -1):

```
Date date1;
Date date2;
[...]
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(date1);
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(date2);
int result = c1.compareTo(c2); // 0 if equal, < 0 if c1 before c2, > 0 if c1 after c2
```

Comment: Any comments for downvoting, or is it just raging? Thank you.